# Thomson Scattering when low intensity light meets an orbital electron

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics

Can you explain to me the reason why Thomson Scattering can not explain what happens when light meets an electron at low intensity, and what does that have to do with light being a wave or particle or relativistic/QM effects?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a low intensity limit for Thomson scattering.
Thomson scattering which is the elastic scattering of electromagnetic radiation by a free charged particle, as explained by classical electromagnetism.
It is just the low-energy limit of Compton scattering and this limit is valid as long as the photon energy is much smaller than the mass energy of the particle, ie $h\nu \ll mc^2$.
The particle's kinetic energy and the photon's frequency do not change as a result of Thomson scattering.

Comment: Wiki: "Effect is significant because it demonstrates that light cannot be explained purely as a wave phenomenon.[4] Thomson scattering, the classical theory of an electromagnetic wave scattered by charged particles, cannot explain shifts in wavelength at low intensity: classically, light of sufficient intensity for the electric field to accelerate a charged particle to a relativistic speed will cause radiation-pressure recoil and an associated Doppler shift of the scattered light,[5] but the effect would become arbitrarily small at sufficiently low light intensities regardless of wavelength."

Comment: *Thus, if we are to explain low-intensity Compton scattering, light must behave as if it consists of particles.* So this is about Compton scattering and not Thomson scattering.